# safe json to java serialization/deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization

I would like to know how you would do this :

I have a java data object. This object contains object attributes that contains object attributes...

I serialize my objects using [json-io](https://code.google.com/p/json-io/). But when deserializing, I want to protect the data if an object fails to deserialize. So I got the idea to json-serialize each attribute before serializing any object. This way, if an attribute fails to deserialize, the object itself is safe.

this means that if I have an object `{a:v1,b:{ba:v2,bb:{bba:v3,bbb:v4}}}`, I will serialize it like this instead : `"{\"a\":\"v1\",\"b\":\"{\\\"ba\\\":\\\"v2\\\",\\\"bb\\\":\\\"{\\\\\\\"bba\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"v3\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"bbb\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"v4\\\\\\\"}\\\"}\"}"`

You see that on a very simple object it becomes very uneasy to read. Imagine with a more complex one !

I would like to do something about it, but I found no good ideas. Maybe the best would be when I read/write the json to call a function able to remove/re-add the "\" where they are needed, but I don't succeed to find the correct algorithm... Any hint ? Or maybe another method ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Confused. How would it fail? Are you receiving the JSON input as an `InputStream`? Also I'm not a fan of JSON-IO -- if you are writing REST services you should default to Jackson or Gson IMO.

Comment: I use it to serialize the data of my app. Consider it's a copy of powerpoint. When json-io tries to restore the fields, if there is a bug in my app, it can fail. In this case, the whole json file can be wasted. I use this trick to avoid it. If there is a bug, only the concerned part is lost

Comment: Do you have some model this fits into, or are you writing this to be generic?  If the former then this is a relatively easy problem as all you need to do is write your own custom serializer/deserializer for said class.  No JSON should look that ugly, BTW... seriously consider switching libraries.  JSON-IO isn't maintained and isn't nearly as efficient or elegant as the other libraries I mentioned.

Comment: No it is to be generic. Ok for switching, but will it make a difference for this current problem ? Hum... You mean I should write my own json-serializer ?

Comment: "Generic" will be ugly if you literally mean 100% generic, arbitrary data. That said, *you should really update your question with more context or I and others will have a hard time helping you.*  And I'd say yes switching would make a difference because (a) It's easier and cleaner to write custom serializers/deserializers and (b) More people know those libraries and could help you.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to explain better. Tomorrow, because I can't think clear after 1am... Thanks a lot for your advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. My approach was wrong. I created a Data object like a Map that contains Data or String. Then, I can safely deserialize Data elements. It means that this time I have a tree, where all the trunk is a safe Data object, and only the leafs are json-serialized generic objects.

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private final Map<String, Data> node = new HashMap<>();//safe tree object

    private final Map<String, String> leafs = new HashMap<>();//unsafe serialized object
}
```

In my previous example, the result would be :

```
//initial object
{a:v1,b:{ba:v2,bb:{bba:v3,bbb:v4}}}
//becomes
{"a":"{v1}","b":{"ba":"{v2}","bb":{"bba":"{v3}","bbb":"{v4}"}}}
```

And the `\` would appear only if one of the unsafe values contains a String.

Thanks a lot Ryan, Talking to you helped me a lot to better define the problems, which is always the first step to the solution.